# Force escaping Special character in XML Marshalling in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, marshalling

I want to force escaping special characters when I use Spring Marshaller. Below code is perfectly working when I use `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller`

**Book Class**

```
package com.odr.core.action;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;
    private String isbn;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=CDATAAdapter.class)
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [name=" + name + ", author=" + author + ", publisher="
            + publisher + ", isbn=" + isbn + ", description=" + description
            + "]";
    }   
}
```

**Object to XML**

```
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(selectedFile));
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler",
                new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void escape(char[] ch, int start, int length,
                            boolean isAttVal, Writer writer)
                            throws IOException {
                        writer.write(ch, start, length);
                    }
                });
        m.marshal(book, writer);
```

**Output:**

```html
<description>

<![CDATA[<p>With hundreds of practice questions and hands-on exercises, <b>SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide</b> covers what you need to know--and shows you how to prepare--for this challenging exam. </p>]]>
</description>
```

But same kind of code is not working when I use org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller, Below is the code

```
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("jaxb.formatted.output", true);
    jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.odr.core.action");
    // com.sun.xml.bind.characterEscapeHandler
    // com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler
    map.put("com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler",
            new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                @Override
                public void escape(char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag,
                        Writer writer) throws IOException {
                    writer.write(ac, i, j);
                }
            });
    jaxb2Marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(map);

    org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller marshaller = jaxb2Marshaller;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    // String fileNamePath = directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileName;

    try {
        // fos = new FileOutputStream(fileNamePath);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
        marshaller.marshal(book, new StreamResult(fos));

        // File f = new File(directory,fileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```html
<description>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;With hundreds of practice questions and hands-on exercises, &lt;b&gt;SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide&lt;/b&gt; covers what you need to know--and shows you how to prepare--for this challenging exam. &lt;/p&gt;]]&gt;</description>
```

The first snippet didn't encode the special characters. But the second snippet which is using Spring did encode though I set property. I have to use Spring in my project for not affecting existing code. Is there any way I can fix it

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? I tried the same code of Jaxb2Marshaller with Spring 4.x and it works for me.

Comment: Im using spring-oxm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Can you share the Book class?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I had the same problem, and I solved it this way.

First things first. You should create two beans. One for the `Jaxb2Marshaller` and another `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`. I'm supposing that you want to keep your configuration, so I'm going to use your code.

Creating the `Jaxb2Marshaller` bean:

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller getJaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("jaxb.formatted.output", true);
    jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.odr.core.action");
    map.put("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler",
            new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                @Override
                public void escape(char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag,
                                   Writer writer) throws IOException {
                    writer.write(ac, i, j);
                }
            });
    jaxb2Marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(map);

    org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller marshaller = jaxb2Marshaller;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
        marshaller.marshal(book, new StreamResult(fos));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    }

    return jaxb2Marshaller;
}
```

Well, I'm using *Java 8* so I changed **com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler** to **com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler** as you can see above.

Creating the `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` bean:

```
@Bean
public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter getMarshallingHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(getJaxb2Marshaller());
}
```

You must notice that I've created my own HttpMessageConverter to solve the problem. That's because Spring uses it's own converter that creates a new `Marshaller` instance everytime it needs to convert a entity or a DTO to XML objetct. So, I think the code below will solve your problem. Hope it helps you.

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

@Configuration
public class XmlParseConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller getJaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("jaxb.formatted.output", true);
        jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.odr.core.action");
        map.put("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler",
                new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void escape(char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag,
                                       Writer writer) throws IOException {
                        writer.write(ac, i, j);
                    }
                });
        jaxb2Marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(map);

        org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller marshaller = jaxb2Marshaller;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
            marshaller.marshal(book, new StreamResult(fos));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        }

        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter getMarshallingHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(getJaxb2Marshaller());
    }
}
```